# How do i chop up an array with a comma between every string?

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, entity-framework, charts

I have an array that i create with this query:

```
public string[] Scores { get; set; } 
var scoresBetted = _context.Bet.Where(i => i.MatchId == id)
.Select(a => a.ScoreBetted).ToArray(); //ScoreBetted type string
Scores = scoresBetted;
```

I now want to chop up the array so that it comes out like this for example: `"1-1","4-2","2-1"` etc. I'm thinking that need to do with with a `foreach` loop but i can't find how i do it.

Why i wanna do this is because i want to dynamically create c3 categories in a chart, and those categories is an array, [example here](https://c3js.org/samples/categorized.html)

Comment: In C# string.Join() is the method. Read about it and use.

Comment: I've tried `var test = string.Join(",", Model.Scores);` but that put's the whole thing in a string like this `"1-1,4-2"`

Comment: How does the Model.ListOfScores look like before?

Comment: Sorry, ListOfScores is Scores, it was called ListOfScores before i turned it into an array instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
var test = string.Join(@",", Model.ListOfScores.Select(x => $"'{x}'"));
```

That means it put each item in `' '` first, then, join your array with separation `,`

Version [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aIZ6BA)

Comment: Why not let `String.Join` do all the work? Also you forgot to add the quotes at the beginning and the end. Like: `var test = @"""" + string.Join(@""",""", new List<string> {"x", "y"}) + @"""";`

Comment: Hmm, That's what i wanted but when i launch the app the categories turns out like this: `categories: [&quot;1-1&quot;,&quot;4-1&quot;]`

Comment: @CarstenFranke `string.Join(@""",""", new List<string> {"x", "y"})` you can try this code and see this doesn't work like OP wants....

Comment: @user10384441 what you need is ' ', not " ". See my answer updated

Comment: If you want to avoid the character encoding, you have to use `Html.Raw` on output, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.Raw) The single quotes may work for now. But if the content of the array gets some special characters, they will be encoded as well. So you should do right from the beginning.

Comment: @ThierryV I get the result that i thought would work with your solution. But in the script it gets wierd, prop because it's javascript and i need to do another step. This is what it turns into [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5f4sqpk/)

Comment: I think you should return the raw data to the client side, and then put each item in ' ' by Javascript

Comment: @CarstenFranke Html.Raw(test) did the job! Thanks everyone!

Comment: @user10384441 glad to help you